# Custom UIActionSheet for iOS

Tags: ios, uiactionsheet

Is it possible to create an action sheet that looks like the attached image for iOS?

[image: screenshot]

This is the screenshot from the Photo app on iOS6, when you press the action button. I really like the way the options are listed as their icons, rather than horizontal buttons with titles.

I looked through Google and also in Apple's [iOS reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html) but I can't seem to find anything that teaches me how to create something like this for my app.

Comment: Related: for "Open in..." see: https://github.com/honkmaster/TTOpenInAppActivity

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can create this by using an Activity View Controller.  It's not the same as an Action Sheet.

See Apple's documentation:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW121