# UIView inside UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, ipad, uialertview

I want to create a custom UIAlertView  to show the view like what's in image

[image]

I want to add icons beside it a textView the text of which is clickable and opens UIWebView.

Is this possible in iPhone? I googled, but did not find how to do this.

Comment: That's android, is it not? iOS and android are **very** different platforms, and using android metaphors on iPhone is likely to lead to rejection by apple.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533507/custom-uiactionsheet-for-ios

and

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130475/adding-images-to-uiactionsheet-buttons-as-in-uidocumentinteractioncontroller

Comment: @Kostis.. thanks, your links made me found app similar to what I want to do in this link. https://github.com/levey/LeveyPopListView

Comment: @Kostis.. I created the popup like what's in the linke that I posted in the previous comment and all ok with me, but if I want to change the size of this popup I changed the values in `bgRect = CGRectInset(rect, POPLISTVIEW_SCREENINSET, 122);` but if I want to change the start point of this popup, how can I do this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me you are trying to create a popUp that doesnt need to be an alert.

If thats the case, this library might help:

[MJPopupViewController](https://github.com/martinjuhasz/MJPopupViewController)

You can create a popUp of any size, that is a normal view. So you can put any other views or controls inside it.